# ubuntu 14.04 Windows transparency

Tags: 14.04, dconf, transparency

I've searched alot but didn't find anywhere, I loved my windows transparency in ubuntu 13.10 (that you could enable by opening dconf editor going to org > compiz > gwd )
And it doesn't seem to work now in ubuntu 14.04 is there another way to make my windows borders transparent? (like that gedit border http://www.techsupportalert.com/files/images/Aero-Glass-Effect-200-151.png)

Answer (score 1):

Transparency requires desktop compositing to work properly.

Install compizconfig-settings-manager and make sure that 'Composite' under the 'general' category is enabled.

Comment: well I think I have it enabled, might be something with settings?
http://s29.postimg.org/nscct92h3/here_it_goes.png

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully transitioned from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and was able to enable windows transparency by first reinstalling (in my case) compizconfig:

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins

Then open conpizconfig manager and go to Accessibility > Opacity > Enable Opacity.

After that go to Misc Options and tweak them.

Then go back to Accessibility > Opacity, Brightness and Saturation > Enable it.

In the Opacity tab, select (grab) what key combinations or mouse buttons to bind to the 
incremental increase or decrease the opacity of active window and change the window opacity based on the window type or title.

Answer (score 0):

Windows opacity on move:

dconf-editor - org compiz profiles unity pluging move : set opacity as you like

Answer (score -1):

This is a wrong info. unity is nothing to do with compoziting anymore basicly the answer to this topic should be: as long as you choose using unity desktop there is no way to enable transparent windows borders because with this ubuntu lts version dconf editor is simply useless and even not necessary.

Comment: As long as I know I use Unity and before I post I checked this for my own use. Although I must admit this is not an answer to the very question which was only about borders. The setting with dconf affects the whole window (on move)... but I think: the setting is called opacity, and maybe my poor English made me wrongly think it is the opposite of transparency, so the setting scale would just be reversed.